# Nautilus stops working frequently

Tags: nautilus, files

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 and in my system(Laptop-Dell Inspiron 5501) nautilus stops working occasionally and I have to kill it and then restart. Any help?

Also `sudo nautilus` works.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately there is not enough information here to offer any suggestions. Could you [edit] your question to explain *when* Nautilus stops working? Is it during long file copies? Is it when accessing files over USB or the network? Is it when accessing directories with millions of files? Every detail you offer makes it more likely that someone can offer an answer.

Comment: If I keep it open on the background minimized, the next time I open it it says Files has stopped working with a force quit and wait option. No issue during copying

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Precision 3541 and have to kill Nautilus occasionally also. Possibly related issue: I can't find any information on why Nautilus frequently runs Locate (the keyboard and touchpad become erratically unresponsive and when open Sysmonitor discover Nautilus has forked a Locate, which completes rapidly, returning normal responses). This may be paranoid, but I suspect government surveillance may piggyback on locate (don't really care except for the annoying hurky-jerky response occasionally).